# Have anyone compiled Tensorflow_federated on Jetson TX2?

Tags: compiler-errors, arm64, tensorflow-federated

Please find the logs here:

```
pip install --requirement "requirements.txt"
```

This is all okay but still the source is not getting compiled

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1052076/jetson-tx2/tensorflow_federated-on-tx2-/

Comment: A bit more information is necessary: which commit of the TFF is being used? What pip packages are installed (run `pip freeze`)? What version of bazel is used?

Note: recent versions of TFF have moved to use the `tf-nightly` pip package, which may conflict/require uninstalling the `tensorflow` pip package.

Comment: pip freeze output attached answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
jetson@jetson-desktop:~$ pip3 freeze
absl-py==0.7.1
apturl==0.5.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astor==0.7.1
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
blinker==1.4
Brlapi==0.6.6
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
conda==4.3.16
cryptography==2.1.4
cupshelpers==1.0
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.29.7
decorator==4.1.2
defer==1.0.6
distro-info===0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1
feedparser==5.2.1
freetype-py==2.1.0.post1
gast==0.2.2
graphsurgeon==0.3.2
grpcio==1.20.1
h11==0.9.0
h5py==2.9.0
html5lib==0.999999999
httplib2==0.9.2
idna==2.8
joblib==0.13.2
Keras-Applications==1.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.9
keyring==10.6.0
keyrings.alt==3.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.10.6
lazr.restfulclient==0.13.5
lazr.uri==1.0.3
louis==3.5.0
lxml==4.2.1
macaroonbakery==1.1.3
Mako==1.0.7
Markdown==3.1
MarkupSafe==1.0
matplotlib==3.1.0
mock==3.0.5
numpy==1.16.3
oauth==1.0.1
oauthlib==2.0.6
olefile==0.45.1
Pillow==6.0.0
portpicker==1.3.1
protobuf==3.7.1
psutil==5.6.2
py-cpuinfo==5.0.0
pycairo==1.16.2
pycosat==0.6.3
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.73
pygobject==3.26.1
PyJWT==1.5.3
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.1.2
pyparsing==2.4.0
pyRFC3339==1.0
python-apt==1.6.4
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-debian==0.1.32
pytz==2018.3
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.22.0
requests-unixsocket==0.1.5
requests3==0.0.0
ruamel.yaml==0.15.96
scikit-learn==0.21.1
scipy==0.19.1
SecretStorage==2.3.1
simplejson==3.13.2
six==1.12.0
sklearn==0.0
ssh-import-id==5.7
system-service==0.3
systemd-python==234
tensorboard==1.13.1
tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1+nv19.5
tensorrt==5.0.6.3
termcolor==1.1.0
torch==1.1.0a0+b457266
torchvision==0.2.2.post3
ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0
uff==0.5.5
unattended-upgrades==0.1
unity-scope-calculator==0.1
unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks==0.1
unity-scope-colourlovers==0.1
unity-scope-devhelp==0.1
unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks==0.1
unity-scope-manpages==0.1
unity-scope-openclipart==0.1
unity-scope-texdoc==0.1
unity-scope-tomboy==0.1
unity-scope-virtualbox==0.1
unity-scope-yelp==0.1
unity-scope-zotero==0.1
urllib3==1.25.2
urllib5==5.0.0
virtualenv==16.6.0
wadllib==1.3.2
webencodings==0.5
Werkzeug==0.15.4
xkit==0.0.0
zope.interface==4.3.2
jetson@jetson-desktop:~$ bazel version
WARNING: ignoring LD_PRELOAD in environment.
WARNING: --batch mode is deprecated. Please instead explicitly shut down your Bazel server using the command "bazel shutdown".
Build label: 0.19.2- (@non-git)
Build target: bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Sat May 18 07:32:25 2019 (1558164745)
Build timestamp: 1558164745
Build timestamp as int: 1558164745
```

I am installing https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/v0.2.0 --> tensorflow_federated v0.2.0

let me know the package requirement and steps to install tensorflow_federated in aarch64?